# error converting field value in table quote_item_option where option id

Tags: quote

Upgrading from 2.1 to 2.2.2 hers a pic of the error.

**error converting field value in table quote_item_option where option id

Unable to unserialize value**

[image: Magento Upgrade]

[image]

[image]

looked at other articles

UPDATE quote_item_option SET value = NULL WHERE value = '';[image]

sigh more.
ok it completed.[image]

Comment: Maybe this could help you https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12411.